# Field 'valorClick' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com um problema, eu adiciono a notícia e aparece-me o erro "Field 'valorClick' doesn't have a default value".
Esse "ValorClick" é um valor que ao clicar no link da notícia adiciona x dinheiro. 
Aqui fica o código de adicionar a notícia

addNotícia.php

```
<?php
include('configdb.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $texto = $_POST['noticia'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];

    #QUERY QUE INSERE NA BASE DE DADOS OS CAMPOS

    $query_addNoticia = "INSERT INTO artigos(titulo, texto, link, activo) VALUES ('$titulo', '$texto','$link',1)";
    $resultado_addNoticia = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_addNoticia) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    if($resultado_addNoticia)
    {
        #SE OS DADOS FOREM INTRODUZIDOS COM SUCESSO NA BASE DE DADOS:
        echo "
        <script language='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Notícia publicada com sucesso. Clique para voltar à página inicial.')
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        #SE OS DADOS NÃO FOREM INTRODUZIDOS COM SUCESSO NA BASE DE DADOS, MENSAGEM DE ERRO:
        echo "
        <script language='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Não foi possível publicar a sua notícia. Tente novamente, sff. Clique para voltar à página inicial.')
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Aqui fica o index.php onde está a form da noticia

```
echo ("<h1>Adicionar notícia</h1>");
                        echo ("<form id='addNoticia' name='addNoticia' method='post' action='addNoticia.php'>");
                        echo ("<p>");
                            echo ("<label for='titulo'>titulo</label>");
                            echo ("<input type='text' name='titulo' id='titulo' />");
                        echo ("</p>");
                        echo ("<p>");
                            echo("<label for='noticia'>noticia</label>");
                            echo("<textarea name='noticia' id='noticia' cols='45' rows='5'></textarea>");
                        echo ("</p>");
                        echo ("<p>");
                            echo("<label for='link'>link</label>");
                            echo("<input type='text' name='link' id='link' />");
                        echo ("</p>");

                            echo("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Adicionar notícia' />");

                            echo("<input type='reset' name='reset' id='reset' value='Limpar Campos' />");

                        echo("</form>");

                        echo("<hr>");
```

[image: Onde Adiciono a notícia]

[image: Erro ao adicionar a noticia]

[image: Tabela]

Comment: Você precisa especificar um valor para `valorClick` ao realizar um `insert`, esse campo está setado como NotNull

Comment: Sim mas este campo não é suposto as pessoas verem. Mas também não pode ser Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O campo `valorClick` está configurado como `NotNull` e não tem um valor `default` na sua tabela, você não pode realizar um `insert` sem informar um valor

Faça:

```
$query_addNoticia = "INSERT INTO artigos(titulo, texto, link, activo, valorClick) VALUES ('$titulo', '$texto','$link',1, 0)";
```

Ou altere a coluna para ter um valor padrão diferente de `NULL`, dessa forma não precisará ficar informando o valor sempre que for fazer um `insert`

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigada!

Comment: @Joyana deu certo?

Comment: Sim, Muito obrigada!